# Xamarin.Android no stack trace in async method

Tags: exception, asynchronous, xamarin, xamarin.android

Anybody maybe found some workaround for this bug:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=30513

?

It drives me crazy... the screenshoot is the exception report I got from async method.

[image]

Comment: Might be because the method is anonymous.

Comment: No, the stack trace should always has its origins. The correct exception must have managed code caller. It's bug that they will fix "soon" which means after app that we develop will be given to owner...

Comment: Fortunately there is something called an update.

Comment: @Cheesebaron can you confirm that this problem is fixed in an update? which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey guys, so I have found workaround for this bug, here is step by step what to do to handle it and let Xamarin.Insights work.

1. Add text file to Android project(name doesn't matter)and set it
   from "Content" in properties to "**AndroidEnvironment**"
2. In the text file you created add that flag:
   ﻿**XA_BROKEN_EXCEPTION_TRANSITIONS=true** - this flag mean that we will use old, Xamarin.Android 4.x exception handling
3. Then add android exception global handler in your droid project, it will handle Android exceptions which normally crashes application before your Xamarin.Insights(or other report tool)would be able to do some work.

`AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += (sender, args) => 
    {
         args.Handled = true;
    }`

And voila, the Xamarin.Insights is ready to work for you :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another one solution which worked for me.
Just add this handler in your Application or main Activity

```
AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += delegate(object sender, RaiseThrowableEventArgs args){
            typeof (System.Exception).GetField("stack_trace", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .SetValue(args.Exception, null);
            throw args.Exception;
        };
```

The explanation is here in the last post https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/45219/stack-trace-not-captured-properly